# Improve Netbeans' javascript documentation/code completion

Tags: netbeans

When I was using Webstorm, I could type something like this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
var gc = canvas.get
```

then press `ctrl+space` after "get", and have it tell me what options I have (in this case, I was looking for `getContext`, but couldn't remember what it was called). It was fairly intelligent, in that it was able to figure out the type of the object I was calling the method on to give me better suggestions.

In NetBeans however, I only get recommendations for methods of `Object`, like `getPrototypeOf`, `getPropertyNames` and `getPropertyDescriptor`.

Is there a way to make NetBeans more intelligent? I'd rather not have to jump back and forth between Webstorm and NetBeans just to take advantage of it's code completion.